# Im trying to change the text of a button using js but its not working (html dom) (give very basic answer)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was just experimenting and making a small game but before that i made buttons for the user to choose the character and when they hover over the character they get to see a bio about it, im a new coder so dont know the concepts of innerhtml but i used ws3schools to use it but it still did not work

i tried to use innerhtml but the text just wouldnt show here is the code for html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <title>Tomoko Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="header">Choose your Tomoko </h1>
    <button onclick="NewPagePo()" onfocus="AddPo()" form="ReButton" id = "ButtonRehanPo">Tomoko Polite <img id="TomoPicL" src="C:\Users\Rehan Muhammad Ali\.vscode\Tomoko\Photos\20221109_054642.jpg" alt="Dog"></button>
    <button onclick="NewPageDa()" onfocus="AddDa()" form="ReButton" id = "ButtonRehanDa">Tomoko Dangerous <img id="TomoPicR" src="C:\Users\Rehan Muhammad Ali\.vscode\Tomoko\Photos\CIMG0093.JPG" alt="Dog"></button>
    <button onclick="NewPageAll()" onfocus="AddAll()" form="ReButton" id = "ButtonRehanAll">Tomoko All-Rounder <img id="TomoPicM" src="C:\Users\Rehan Muhammad Ali\.vscode\Tomoko\Photos\20211214_192451.jpg" alt="Dog"></button>
    <p id="p1">Hi</p>
</body>
</html>
```

on the buttons it says
onfocus="AddAll()"
thats a js function where i put in the text

```
function NewPagePo() {
  open("indexPo.html", "_self");
}

function NewPageAll() {
  open("indexAll.html", "_self");
}

function NewPageDa() {
  open("indexDa.html", "_self");
}

function Back() {
  open("index.html", "_self");
}

function AddAll() {
  document.getElementById("ButtonRehanAll").innerHTML = "Test1";
}
```

and thats basically it.
and if you want to review the css and see if it can be improved, im all ears
css:

```
/*                                    CSS Style Sheet                                 */


/* Buttons */

#ButtonRehanDa {
  /* Standard button code */
  border: 10;
  border-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  font-size: 10;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  transition: duration 1.3s;
  margin-left: 0.60in;
  image-resolution: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#ButtonRehanAll {
  /* Standard button code */
  border: 10;
  border-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  font-size: 10;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  transition: duration 1.3s;
  margin-left: 0.60in;
  image-resolution: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#ButtonRehanPo {
  /* Standard button code */
  border: 10;
  border-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  font-size: 10;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
  transition: duration 1.3s;
  margin-left: 0.60in;
  image-resolution: 0;
  text-align: center;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  /* Additional */
  margin-left: 125px;
}
#Back {
  border: 10;
  border-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  font-size: 10;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: wheat;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 90%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.19rem;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}


/* Images */


#TomoPicR {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
#TomoPicL {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
#TomoPicM {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  float: right;
  border-radius: 10%;
}
#imgDesign {
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  border: 6px solid black;
}


/* Hover */

#ButtonRehanAll:hover {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 135, 253);
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(240, 194, 107);
}
#ButtonRehanPo:hover {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 135, 253);
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(240, 194, 107);
}
#ButtonRehanDa:hover {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border-color: rgb(0, 135, 253);
  font-weight: 700;
  background-color: rgb(240, 194, 107);
}
#Back:hover {
  border: 10;
  border-color: rgb(0, 135, 253);
  padding: 10px;
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  font-size: 10;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(240, 194, 107);
  border-radius: 30px;
  width: 20.5%;
  height: 90.5%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 1.19rem;
}

/* Other */

.header {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", "Tahoma", "Geneva", "Verdana", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.H1 {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 250%;
  text-align: center;
}
body {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the event `onfocus`? This means that the function is called first when the button has the focus (i.e. if you press Tab until that button is highligted). If you try other events, such as `onmouseover` you may get the effect you want. I haven't tried your code, but it seems to be correct... IF it's meant to react on focus :)

Comment: @Mr_Glacier, Gowire is right - I pasted your code into jsFiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9q7w32nx/) and tabbed through the buttons to #ButtonRehanAll and the text was inserted as expected. My guess is you're confusing MouseOver with Focus.  Follow Gowire's advice and change onfocus to onmouseover and see how you go.

Comment: I also noticed that there are two errors listed as I tabbed through the other buttons - "AddPo is not defined" and "AddDa is not defined" - you have used these as the onfocus() handlers for those buttons but have not defined them in your Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is focused after being clicked on (or navigated to with the keyboard). You're looking for the 'onmouseover' event, instead of the 'onfocus' event on your buttons.

That said, the <button> element is really just for in-page interaction, not navigation. If you're navigating to other pages you should be using the <a> element.

Comment: Also after i stop hovering on my button i how do i make the original code come back

Comment: You can either change your code to replace the text using CSS on hover instead of using Javascript or you can change up your javascript, have it store the initial innerHtml value of the button before you change it, and add a mouseout/onmouseout event which reverts it to that value